# How to open/access GeoPackage file?

Tags: gis

I'm trying to get the coordinates of regions in New Zealand, and have downloaded a `gpkg` file from http://www.gadm.org/country (options: Country: New Zealand, File format: Geopackage (SpatiaLite)) but am unable to open the file, and am unable to find anything online that points me in the right direction.

I'm hoping someone on here is able to help me out?

Comment: What program are you using? Please [edit] your question to add more information.

Comment: There's a hint in the very same page you linked: *The "geopackage" format is the a very good general spatial data file format (for vector data). It is based on the SpatiaLite format, and **can be read by software using GDAL/OGR, including QGIS and ArcMap.***

Comment: I'd look inside the `.deb|.dpkg|squashfs` file, and see where it's trying to install itself; as I suspect it's trying to install in a location your $USER (user account) doesn't have access to, and a `sudo`  [install] may work.  warning:  I don't know the file you're trying to extract, but I'd look inside it before I let it overwrite any fs (filesystem) i cared about first.

Comment: @guiverc It isn't trying to install anything. It can't. It was a mistake now corrected with edits of the OP.

Comment: hmm I am not sure exactly what you want to see, but I was able to see quite a lot of information in the file using `sqlitebrowser` - run `sudo apt install sqlitebrowser` and then `sqlitebrowser`, then "Open Database", select "All Files" in the correct directory, and select the gpkg file. Does that help?

Comment: @Zanna Thank you, if you added that as an answer I will also accept it, it's exactly what I did. Unfortunately the database is extremely confusing and I'm having a tough time figuring out what's going on in it >.<

Comment: @MichaelBay Yea I saw that, but am having trouble using those on Linux :)

Comment: I suggest you ask a specific question about installing the software you want, provided it exists for Linux and you're having trouble installing it.

Comment: did you try `sudo apt install qgis`? If I open the file in qgis by typing `qgis <filename>.gpkg` it works... it's still quite confusing, but maybe less so than with sqlitebrowser...